# MongoDB WriteConcern impact on replication

Tags: mongodb

In general, MongoDB will replicate from a Primary to Secondaries asynchronously, based on number of write operations, time and other factors by shipping *oplog* from primary to secondaries.

When describing WriteConcern options, MongoDB [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-write-concern/) states "...primary waits until the required number of secondaries acknowledge the write before returning write concern acknowledgment".  This seems to suggest that a WriteConcern other than "w:1" would replicate to at least some of the members of the replica set in a blocking manner, potentially avoiding log shipping.

The basic question I'm trying to answer is this: if every write is using WriteCocnern of "majority", would MongoDB ever have to use log shipment?  In other words, is using WriteCocnern of "majority" also controls replication timing?

I would like to better understand how MongoDB handles WriteConcern of "majority".  A few obvious options:

1. Primary sends write requests to *every* Secondary, and blocks the thread until majority respond with acknowledgment
   or
2. Primary *pre-selects* Secondaries first and sends requests to only those secondaries, blocking the thread until all chosen secondaries respond with acknowledgment
   or
3. Something much smarter than either of these options

If Option 1 is used, in most cases (assuming equidistant placement of secondaries) *all* secondaries will have received the write operation by the time Write completes, and there's high probability (although not a guarantee) *all* secondaries will have applied it.  If true, this behavior enables use cases where writes need to be reflected on Secondaries quicker than typical asynchronous replication process.

Obviously WriteConcern of "majority" will incur performance penalty, but this may be acceptable for specific use cases where read operations may target Secondaries (e.g. ReadPreference of "nearest") and desire more recent data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> if every write is using WriteConcern of "majority", would MongoDB ever have to use log shipment?

Replication in MongoDB uses what is termed as the [oplog](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-oplog/). This is a record of all operations on the primary (the only node that accept writes).

Instead of pushing the oplog into the secondaries, the secondaries long-pull on the oplog of the primary. If replication chaining is allowed (the default), then a secondary can also pull the oplog from another secondary. So scenario 1 & 2 you posted are not the reality with MongoDB replication as of MongoDB 4.0.

The details of the replication process is described in MongoDB Github wiki page: [Replication Internals](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/wiki/Replication-Internals).

To quote the relevant parts regarding your question:

> If a command includes a write concern, the command will just block in its own thread until the oplog entries it generates have been replicated to the requested number of nodes. The primary keeps track of how up-to-date the secondaries are to know when to return. A write concern can specify a number of nodes to wait for, or majority.

In other words, the secondaries continually report back to the primary how far along it has applied the oplog into its own dataset. Since the primary knows the timestamp that the write took place, once a secondary has applied that timestamp, it can tell that the write has propagated to that secondary. To satisfy the write concern, the primary simply waits until a determined number of secondaries have applied the write timestamp.

Note that only the thread specifying the write concern is waiting for this acknowledgment. All other threads are not blocked due to this waiting at all.

Regarding to you other question:

> Obviously WriteConcern of "majority" will incur performance penalty, but this may be acceptable for specific use cases where read operations may target Secondaries (e.g. ReadPreference of "nearest") and desire more recent data.

To achieve what you described, you need a combination of read and write concerns. See 
[Causal Consistency and Read and Write Concerns](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/causal-consistency-read-write-concerns/index.html) for more details on this subject.

Write majority is typically used for:

- Ensuring that the write will not be rolled back in the event of the primary failure.
- Ensuring that the application is not writing so fast that the provisioned hardware of the replica set cannot cope with the traffic; i.e. it can act as a backpressure mechanism.
- In combination with [read concern](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/read-concern/index.html), provide the client with differing levels of consistency guarantees.

These points assume that the write majority was acknowledged and the acknowledgment was received by the client. There are multiple different failure scenario that are possible (as expected with a distributed system that needs to cope with unreliable network), but those are beyond the scope of this discussion.

Comment: Thanks for sharing Github wiki, very helpful!

Comment: To clarify: when Primary is handling write concern of "majority", does it simply wait for necessary number of secondaries to process oplog entries in their general flow?  It may end up waiting a while depending on how often Background Sync kicks in or how much work it has to do.  Is there anything Primary does to kick off Background Sync, or re-prioritize it or affect it in any way?

Comment: No, the primary has no control over what happen on the secondaries. It just receive acknowledgment from them, and wait for them if required by the write concern setting. In a well-provisioned replica set, secondaries are only seconds behind the primary since they're designed to keep up as quickly as possible, so they can take over the primary's duties at a moment's notice. This is the secondaries' main purpose, so they're very aggressive about applying the oplog as quickly as possible.